# Socket.io server on "connection" not firing, same for the client event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Hi tried to build an express backend using socket io but for whatever reason I just dont get the connection events to be fired. I am using version 3.1.2 on the server and client, so thats not the issue. As soon as I start the client app, I get some log in the express server looking like this:

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2021:11:14:10 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Noo0Wgb&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 149 "-" "node-XMLHttpRequest"

But the on connection event does not fire on either side.

```html
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./src/config/general");
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

const SECURITY_KEY = process.env.SECURITYKEY;

//database
const connect = require("./src/config/database/connect");


app.set("json spaces", 2);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("combined"));

//controllers
const ExchangeController = require("./src/api/exchange/exchange.controller");
const exchangeController = new ExchangeController(io);  //initially wanted to socket logic in that file, but even in the server.js its not working either
const LogController = require("./src/api/log/log.controller");
const logController = new LogController();
const StrategyController = require("./src/api/strategy/strategy.controller");
const strategyController = new StrategyController();

app.set("json spaces", 2);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.use("/api/exchange", exchangeController.router);
app.use("/api/log", logController.router);
app.use("/api/strategy", strategyController.router);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("incoming socket connection");
  socket.on("buy", async (data) => {
    try {
      let payload = JSON.parse(data);
      let symbols = payload.symbol.split(",");
      let strategy;

      if (payload.hasOwnProperty("strat")) {
        strategy = payload.strat;
      }
      if (payload.security == SECURITY_KEY) {
        for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
          exchangeManager.performStrategy(strategy, symbols[i]);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("io.on", error.message);
    }
  });
});


app.listen(config.PORT, async () => {
  await connect();
  console.log(`server started on port ${config.PORT}`);
});
```

Client side testing code

```html
//client.js
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000")
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
  
});

socket.on('error', function (socket) {
    console.log('error!');
  
});
```

I am completely lost on this and have tried everything without any success.

Comment: Not really sure with my comment, but have you specified in the server side that you're binding to port `3000` ? I think the express js server recognizes that there is a request incoming (as shown by the log). However, nothing in the express js code is binded to the port `3000`, so the express js server does nothing in return

Comment: I have updated the initial post and server side code to include the app.listen method I have implemented thats binding to port 3000. If I dont specify port 3000 on the client app, the server does not even put out any logs. So Port binding is working at 3000

Comment: I solved the error myself. I was doing app.listen instead of server.listen lol, sometimes its just as simple as that after 5 hours of trying stuff..

Comment: I also feel the pain of doing that... oh and btw if you find out the answer to your own question I believe you can answer it yourself and accept it

Answer (score 0):

error solves by switching app.listen to server.listen, my bad.